# Asus TUF FX504GD has 4 memory slots instead of 2

Tags: memory, motherboard, asus-laptop, memory-limit

I have purchased an `ASUS FX504GD` and based on task amnager and cpu-z there are `4` slots available. I also own a HP and over there it shows clearly 2 slots available. On their official site says `2 slots available`. Can I add more RAM like 64 GB RAM?

The offcial specs: https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-FX504/specifications/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFawx.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [ASUS FAQ](https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1038321)

> **Why does GL12CP only support 2 Memory slots when it has 4 Memory slots ?**
>
> The original GL12CP includes 4 Memory slots. This was to allow our
>   users to test compatibility issues with 3rd party memory.   However,
>   we realized this could be confusing to the user so we removed this
>   feature from the GL12CP and will now include only 2 memory slots in
>   future versions.
>
> Q : I found 4 memory slots in my device. What would
>   happen if I plugs four Memory into the four slots?
>   A : The device
>   will only detect and recognize the capacity of two DIMM Memory.
>
> Please configure the memory installation as the following  :
>   Choose
>   either DIMM_A1 or DIMM_B1
>   Choose either DIMM_A2 or DIMM_B2

Comment: Thank you, you saved me from wasting time on buying another pair of memory